# Need to parse very large XML file PHP

Tags: php

Hi I'm trying yo use XMLParser the parse an xml file

I need to end up with something like this
productID: xerox_106r0116
name: Xerox zwart, tonercartridge met grote capaciteit (tot 32.000 pag.) (106R01163)

However what I get is this

## text: xerox_106r0116

## text: Xerox zwart, tonercartridge met grote capaciteit (tot 32.000 pag.) (106R01163)

Does anyone know how to properly parse with XMLParser

The XML is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products>
<product>
<productID>xerox_106r01163</productID>
<name>Xerox zwart, tonercartridge met grote capaciteit (tot 32.000 pag.) (106R01163)</name>
<price currency="EUR">165.77</price>
<productURL>http://www.centralpoint.nl/tracker/index.php?tt=534_251713_1_&amp;r=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.centralpoint.nl%2Ftoners-laser-cartridges%2Fxerox%2Fzwart-tonercartridge-met-grote-capaciteit-tot-32000-pag-art-106r01163-num-17879%2F</productURL>
<imageURL>https://www02.cp-static.com/objects/low_pic/3/3a9/117949_toners-laser-cartridges-xerox-zwart-tonercartridge-met-grote-capaciteit-tot-32000-pag-106r01163.jpg</imageURL>
<description><![CDATA[Black Toner Cartridge, Phaser 7760
Our Phaser 7760
 toner cartridges utilize a revolutionary toner manufacturing process where toner is chemically grown and processed into very small and consistent particles, resulting in sharper, high-gloss image quality, an increased range of colors, enhanced fine-line detail and superior reliability. Our longer-life toner cartridges reduce the need for customer interaction, and the Black toner cartridges print up to 32,000 pages each at 5% average area coverage.]]></description>
<categories>
<category path="toners &amp; lasercartridges">toners &amp; lasercartridges</category>
</categories>
<additional>
<field name="brand">Xerox</field>
<field name="producttype">zwart, tonercartridge met grote capaciteit (tot 32.000 pag.)</field>
<field name="deliveryCosts">0.00</field>
<field name="SKU">106R01163</field>
<field name="brand_and_type">Xerox 106R01163</field>
<field name="stock">Op voorraad</field>
<field name="thumbnailURL">https://www02.cp-static.com/objects/thumb_pic/3/3a9/117949_toners-laser-cartridges-xerox-zwart-tonercartridge-met-grote-capaciteit-tot-32000-pag-106r01163.jpg</field>
<field name="deliveryTime">1 werkdag</field>
<field name="imageURLlarge">https://www02.cp-static.com/objects/high_pic/3/3a9/117949_toners-laser-cartridges-xerox-zwart-tonercartridge-met-grote-capaciteit-tot-32000-pag-106r01163.jpg</field>
<field name="categoryURL">http://www.centralpoint.nl/toners-laser-cartridges/</field>
<field name="EAN">0095205224016</field>
</additional>
</product>
</products>
```

Comment: Where's your attempt to solve this problem? Without any code shared, it's close to impossible to guess where your attempt went wrong. And the given XML file does not look like "very large" to not try something

Answer (score 3):

For very large files I use a combination of [XMLReader](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.xmlreader.php) (acts as a cursor going forward on the document stream) and [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/es/class.simplexmlelement.php). In your case it would be something like this:

```
$xml = new XMLReader();
if(!$xml->open($FILE_NAME)){
    die("Error opening the XML file");
}

//Process XML with the product list
while($xml->read()){
    if($xml->nodeType==XMLReader::ELEMENT && $xml->name == 'product'){
        $product_xml = $xml->readOuterXml();

        //Getting attributes
        $product = simplexml_load_string($product_xml, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOBLANKS && LIBXML_NOWARNING);
        $product_id = (string)$product->productID;
        $product_name = (string)$product->name;

        //Then do something with product_id and product_name...
        echo "ProductID: ".$product_id." name:".$product_name;
    }
}
$xml->close();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: would that allow me to parse a 2GB feed with 32MB RAM - I understood that SimpleXML loads it into memory, but I'll give it a try

Comment: I'll go with this for a while, seems to perform well parsing > 50,000 products

Comment: I've not tried with 2GB, but in theory it should work. The XMLReader does not try to load the entire document into memory. This solution gather the data you need to perform an operation, then skip to the next node. Does not try to build massive data structures from a massive XML document.

Answer (score -1):

here is what i use for xml parsing, it loads xml document in to a DOMDocument object and you can work from that. See if that helps

```
    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    try{
        $xml->loadXML($string, LIBXML_NSCLEAN);
    }catch(\Exception $e){
       throw new Exception('Invalid XML structure');
    }
    return $xml;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the tip but  I need code that is robust and performs well. DomDocument  is a memory hog and would time out in no time. I need to stream it not load it in to memory

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - which parts are relevant to read a "very large" file?